# Google drive API does not find my folder when using the drive.files.list

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I've tried this to retrieve a list of files from specific folder on my google drive, using JavaScript. Whenever I dont use the driveId, it prints 30 items from my drive, but I want to reach an specific folder. Error says that it does not find my drive. I did not include the erro handling part of the code.

```
 drive.files.list({
        corpora: 'drive',
        driveId: '1_9NczxZoAvNxYOw7yybTAvWFq4S9unMp',
        includeItemsFromAllDrives : true,
        pageSize: 30,
        pageToken: pageToken ? pageToken : '',
        supportsAllDrives: true,
        fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    }
```

Comment: The handling part of the code is not important?

Answer (score 0):

There's only 30 items and there doesn't seem to be any real pagination - and so you might not even reach until the ID of that folder. If the folder is in the root directory, set the `parentId` to `root`. Else, just set the ID of the folder as the `parentId`, to list it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

### You can specify the parent folder with the query parameter `q`

Besides, increase the page size if you want more than 30 results.

Sample

```
drive.files.list({
        corpora: 'drive',
        driveId: '1_9NczxZoAvNxYOw7yybTAvWFq4S9unMp',
        includeItemsFromAllDrives : true,
        q: '"PASTE HERE THE ID OF THE FOLDER" in parents'
        pageSize: 1000,
        supportsAllDrives: true,
        fields: 'files(id, name)',
    }
```

See [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) for other samples of possible queries.